# CodeIgniter - Exists an alternative to database migration for production environments?

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, versioning, production-environment

Currently I am developing a web application with CodeIgniter. The application has a database and I am sure, that in later versions the database will be change.

Example:
In `v1.0` of the application exists a table `entries` with three columns. In `v1.1` I add an additional column and remove another one of the table.

A user is already using `v1.0` of the application. Now the user upload the newest version, `v1.1`. In this case, the database should be updated.

How can I handle this and similar cases?

I know that there exists a [Migration](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/migration.html) class. But as far as I know, automatically migration should not be used in production environment. Additionally the Migration class do not take care of the values saved in the database.

So what is the alternative?

If it matters, I am working with SQLite3 as database.

Thank you for your help!

---

From my point of view, the user of a web application should not take care of the database. E.g.: No WordPress user needs to do anything with the database, when a new version releases. The CMS handles the database by itself.